# Facebook Like Box Not Appearing in FireFox or Internet Explorer

Tags: facebook-likebox

I'm trying to embed a Facebook Like Box from this Facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/StansfieldVending. I am not showing faces, border, or the header, and am using the 'dark' color scheme. I am showing the stream. I have used the HTML5 and iframe version and both work in Chrome, but won't show up in Internet Explorer 10 or FireFox 22 - on my site, or on the developers.facebook.com page where you generate the code.

It seems like something is wrong with the Facebook page, because when I plug another Facebook page into the site, it shows up fine in all three browsers. Has anyone encountered this issue, and what is the recommended resolution?

Comment: Can’t reproduce that, works fine when I put the page address into the code generator. Do you have any restrictions on that page – age, alcohol, …?

Comment: I am having same issue. If I use the browser with Win 8 it views fine but when I go to desktop and use explorer I cannot see the Facebook like box, oddly enough it is only on some like boxes. I have three embedded on one page and only one doesn't show but worked earlier today. Script is identical to the other 2 like boxes except the name of the site.